# SSIS how handle var length in Derived column to avoid truncation

Tags: ssis

I have this setup like in illustration attached, hope it clear enough. I load all xls files in loop from given folder.
While implementing new `Derived Column` box to record `FileName` from my loop I got truncation error. My variable initially was set to `CCS.xls` (Len=7, shortest name ).

I tried to increase Length in Derived Column Editor but failed to do this, as it's not active, I can't not type anything there, then I track that that original Length came from `Variables` value. In Variable windows I have DataType = String and no any option to set length.

So for now I made dummy empty file with looong `CCS____1.xls` name to avoid this problem and it works OK. But want to learn other  good way to avoid this problem, looks like in this setup for data connection I need to use file with longest name (?)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the Length property to 50 or larger manually in Advanced Editor.

Right-Click on the Derived column->Show Advanced Editor->Input and Output Properties->Derived Column Output->Output Columns->the new Column->Data Type Properties->Length

[image: Advanced Editor]

[image: Result]